Quantum Ergodic Theorem: why $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ is used instead of $-\Delta$?
I'm studying the proof of Quantum Ergodic Theorems in the book Partial Differential Equations II: Qualitative Studies of Linear Equations (3rd edition) by Michael E. Taylor. The book includes the reasoning he published in his article Variations on Quantum Ergodic Theorems in 2015.  The background of the theorem is as follows:

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold, with Laplace operator $\Delta$, and set $\Lambda = \sqrt{-\Delta}$. Let $\{u_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(M)$ consisting of eigenfunctions, $\Lambda u_k = \lambda_k u_k, \lambda_k \to +\infty$.

I understand that $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator, but the reasoning behind preferring $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ in this context is unclear to me. What are the advantages or specific reasons for this choice? I want to reproduce the proof using $-\Delta$ because the physical interpretation is more direct, and I know it is proven with $-\Delta$ in other contexts (Semiclassical Analysis, for example), but I want to follow Taylor's proof. Thanks.
EDIT:
I will add the proof of one proposition where I don't know if $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ could be replaced for $-\Delta$. The statement is as follows:

Let $A\in OPS^0(M)$, with principal symbol $\sigma(A)\in C^\infty(T^*M\backslash 0)$, homogeneous of degree 0. Then $$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(Au_k,u_k)=\int\limits_{X}\sigma(A)dS.$$

Here, $\{u_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ are the eigenfunctions of $\sqrt{-\Delta}$, $dS$ is an invariant measure for the smooth flow generated by the principal symbol of $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ over $X=S^*M$. The proof uses that
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k}e^{-t\lambda_{k}}(Au_{k},u_{k})& =\sum_k(Au_k,e^{-t\Lambda}u_k)  \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}Ae^{-t\Lambda}.
\end{aligned}$$
And a parametric construction for the exponential yields
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Tr}Ae^{-t\Lambda}& \sim\left(\int\limits_{X}\sigma(A)dS\right)\mathrm{Tr}e^{-t\Lambda}  \\
&=\left(\int\limits_{X}\sigma(A)dS\right)\sum\limits_{k}e^{-t\lambda_{k}}.
\end{aligned}$$
Would it be possible to replace $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ with $-\Delta$ in an easy way?

It is difficult to answer this question without more context as to how $\Lambda$ is used in the proofs

@whpowell96 You are right, sorry. I can try to explain it. Where I think there is a "problem" with $-\Delta$ is when considering the Local Weyl Law, as it used some properties of $\operatorname{Tr}e^{-t\sqrt{-\Delta}}$. I think it is important to consider the eigenvalues of \sqrt{-\Delta} rather than $-\Delta$, but I don't know exactly why. Also time evolution of a PDO A is given by $A_t = e^{-it\sqrt{-\Delta}} A e^{it\sqrt{-\Delta}}$, but I think it can be replaced by $-\Delta$.

It would help if you could add specific context to your post so people could answer your question wirthout having to search up the paper in question

@whpowell96 of course, thanks. I've edited the question
